# Finding words in a file

Tags: c++, string, vector, character, argv

This function buildTree that reads an text input (contained in the file named in argv[1]). Then, I am opening the file, reading character by character, if there is a new line ("if (token == '\n')") keep track of this line number and store it in a vector to access it later. Next it breaks it into a sequence of words (using any character other than a digit or an alphabetical symbol as the terminator). This is where I'm getting an error. I am then trying to add each character to a string and then when the token is a digit or an alphabetical symbol, then push the string into a vector so I can access it later. Is my logic right? And also can you help with my error when pushing each word into a vector.

Sorry if confusing

```
BinarySearchTree buildTree (char *argv[]){

    ifstream file;
    vector<char *> V;
    int line = 0;
    vector<int> LineNumber;
    file.open(argv[1],ios::in);

    char token;
    string word[] = {};


    if (file.is_open()){
        token = file.get();//reads the next character from a stream
        if (token == '\n')
            line++;
        LineNumber.push_back(line);
        while (token!= ' ' || '0' || '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' ||'6' || '7' || '8' || '9'){
        //while character is not space, digit, or non-alphabetic character
            word += token;//adds character to string array *error here
        }
        V.push_back(word);//adds word to vector *error here
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while` condition check will not do what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
while (token!= ' ' || '0' || '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' ||'6' || '7' || '8' || '9')
```

You have to compare it individually, `token != '0' && token != '1' ...`. However, you can always take advantage of the C standard library (that's what it's there for.)

```
#include <cctype>

while (!std::isspace(token) && !std::isdigit(token))
```

Also, you don't need a while loop here. Change it to `if`.

Secondly, you're trying to concatenate a `char` to a `string[]`. You probably meant to declare a `string` instead.

```
std::string word = "";
```

Finally, your `vector` is declared with a value_type of `char*`, but you're trying to push_back a string. Change it to:

```
std::vector<std::string> V;
```

---

The above corrects the immediate errors in your code, but probably doesn't address the core issue. From what I understand, you're trying to only find strings consisting of alphabetical characters (no digits, spaces, or punctuation characters.) Your condition merely becomes `if (std::isalpha(token))` because that excludes the other three.

Secondly, there isn't a loop in your code. You're only reading one character. You can use `while (std::getline(file, input))` to read your file line by line. Due to the nature of streams, the loop will terminate once there is nothing else to read from the stream. Therefore, your code becomes:

```
if (file.is_open()){
    std::string input;
    while (std::getline(file, input))
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
        {
            token = input[i];
            if (token == '\n')
            {
                line++;
            }
            LineNumber.push_back(line);

            if (std::isalpha(token))
            {
                word += token;
            }
        }
        V.push_back(word);
        word = "";
    }
}
```

Note the `word = ""`. You need to blank it before building the next word.

Also, you might want to check if word is empty before pushing it into the vector (to avoid blank entries in your vector):

```
if (word.size()) V.push_back(word);
```

Comment: Thank you! This really is helpful